# Round outcome Fraction Apache Math Common

Tags: apache, math, rounding, fractions

Is it possible to round the fraction, e.g., `3/2` becomes `1+1/2` and `11/2` becomes `5+1/2` that is produced using [Apache Common Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html)?

**Attempt**

```
Fraction f = new Fraction(3, 2);

System.out.println(f.abs());

FractionFormat format = new FractionFormat();

String s = format.format(f);

System.out.println(s);
```

results in:

```
3 / 2
3 / 2
```

Comment: Do you mean to round it off to the nearest integer?  Or something else?  Do you want to round the 1/2 up, down, or to the even integer?

Comment: @Teepeemm Perhaps `round up` is incorrect. If `7/4` then it should be `1 3/4`

Comment: So you want to separate the fraction into its integer part and proper fraction part, instead of the improper fraction you're getting.

Comment: It appears `Fraction.intValue()` gets the first part, and you can subtract for the rest.  Or is my reading of the API incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you are looking for is a [Mixed Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Mixed_numbers).

Since I don't think Apache Fractions has this built in, you can use the following custom formatter:

```
public static String formatAsMixedNumber(Fraction frac) {
    int sign = Integer.signum(frac.getNumerator())
            * Integer.signum(frac.getDenominator());
    frac = frac.abs();
    int wholePart = frac.intValue();
    Fraction fracPart = frac.subtract(new Fraction(wholePart));
    return (sign == -1 ? "-" : "")
            + wholePart
            + (fracPart.equals(Fraction.ZERO) ? ("") : ("+" + fracPart));
}
```